# Puppeteer problem using JS path selector through DOM to input login text

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, screen-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to have Puppeteer log into a variety of sites.

On one site, the following code works fine:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.site1.com');
await page.waitFor('input[name=UserID]');
await page.$eval('input[name=UserID]', el => el.value = 'myusername1');
```

This does not work on another site.  The username is a selector called `id="username"`. So I ran it `headless=false` and it opens the login page, and thus I got the full JS path to the selector called "username", that is:

```js
document.querySelector("body > banno-web > bannoweb-login").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > jha-card > article > bannoweb-login-form").shadowRoot.querySelector("#username")
```

I am just looking to input the username, but I do not know the syntax of getting to the username field through the DOM.  This does not work:

```js
await page.$eval('input[id=username]', el => el.value = 'myusername2');
```

Comment: `input#username`

Answer (score 2):

### Using `page.evaluate`

You can use [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to run JavaScript on the page itself.

**Code Sample**

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector("body > banno-web > bannoweb-login")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > jha-card > article > bannoweb-login-form")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("#username")
  .value = 'myusername2';
});
```

### Using `elementHandle.type`

However, complex applications with special event handlers for focus, input, etc. like Angular pages do not work well when the value of an input field is changed like that. To behave more human-like, we should use functions like [`elementHandle.type`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options) instead.

**Code Sample**

```js
const jsHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(
  () => document.querySelector("body > banno-web > bannoweb-login")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("div > jha-card > article > bannoweb-login-form")
  .shadowRoot.querySelector("#username")
);
const elementHandle = await jsHandle.asElement();
await elementHandle.type('myusername2');
```

This code uses `page.evaluateHandle` and `jsHandle.asElement` to get the ElementHandle from the JavaScript selector. After that, `elementHandle.type` is used to fill in the text.

Comment: The first part works, the second (page.type) does not.  So thank you!  However, for some reason when I add the username and then password using code similar to your first snippet... the login button does not become active.

Comment: @downstairs Maybe you have to behave more "human-like" and use `page.type` instead, hard to say without seeing the page. The first snippet only works when you select the option "Copy selector" instead of "Copy JS path" when using DevTools.

Comment: I did "copy selector" and got just this:

#username

So I used just this code:

```page.type('#username', 'myusername2');```

And the output through Powershell is:

(node:13608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #username

Comment: @downstairs Can you show the HTML of the page or do you have a link to the page? It will be hard to debug without seeing the code. :)

Comment: @downstairs Improved my answer. It should work with the second code snippet.